# error while installing packages opensubmit ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: error-handling, pip

I am getting following error while installing following packages

https://github.com/troeger/opensubmit/wiki/Installation-Instructions

```
opensubmit-web configure
```

> Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-f5Js12-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/pycrypto
>       Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log

pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: You are getting this error when doing what? Turning on your machine? Logging in? Trying to run some program? What program? On what Ubuntu? Please [edit] your question and give us some information.

Comment: @terdon see edits

Comment: Are you installing something with `pip`? Using what command? What version of pip? What version of python? What version of Ubuntu? Can you install other packages with `pip`? You need to *explain what you are doing*. Don't assume we can guess or guess correctly.

Comment: Can you post the log file mentioned in the error? `/home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log` e.g. `cat /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log`.
Also, which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @OludareFajimolu please update according to my comment above.

Comment: errro removed by installing sudo apt-get install python-dev

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error while installing opensubmit ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/872863/error-while-installing-opensubmit-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

The error was removed by installing python-dev in Ubuntu 14.04.  python-dev is a dependency of a package that is recommended by python-pip in Ubuntu 16.04. The package that is recommended by python-pip that has python-dev as a dependency is python-dev-all which is not available from the default repositories in Ubuntu 14.04.

```
sudo apt install python-dev
```

Comment: The error comes from a file access error (permission denied). He re-asked his question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872863/error-while-installing-opensubmit-ubuntu-14-04-lts).

Comment: I am **not** the asker. Yes, that command returns the error. Just follow the link I embedded in my previous comment.