# error while installing opensubmit ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: pip

I am getting error while installing opensubmit at

https://github.com/troeger/opensubmit/wiki/Installation-Instructions

using command `opensubmit-web configure`

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1432, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 599, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1845, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 296, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/opensubmit-web'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error while installing packages opensubmit ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/872853/error-while-installing-packages-opensubmit-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the process the file `/usr/local/bin/opensubmit-web` should be removed (`os.unlink(src)`) which fails with a missing permission.

Either try rerunning your command with root privileges:

```
sudo opensubmit-web configure
```

or you need to become the owner of the file:

```
sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/bin/opensubmit-web
```

Then simply execute your command `opensubmit-web configure` as before.

Comment: If this works please mark this and your [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872853/error-while-installing-packages-opensubmit-ubuntu-14-04-lts) about this as solved.

Comment: after running above commands error persists

Comment: can you try following the [full installation log](https://github.com/troeger/opensubmit/wiki/Installation-Log)?